# Spring Boot JMS message conversion to IBM MQ message error

Tags: spring-boot, type-conversion, jms, ibm-mq

I'm trying to connect to IBM MQ from my Spring Boot project to put a message in a local queue. I'm using :

1. JAVA 20
2. IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer Version: 7.5.0.2
3. Spring-boot 3.0.5

Dependencies :

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>wmq.jmsra</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Controller:

```java
@RestController
@EnableJms
@RequestMapping("/test/")
public class IBMController {

    @Value("${ibm.mq.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.port}")
    private Integer port;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.queueManager}")
    private String queueManager;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.channel}")
    private String channel;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.receiveTimeout}")
    private long receiveTimeout;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.username}")
    private String user;
    @Value("${ibm.mq.password}")
    private String password;

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    @RequestMapping("send")
    public String sendMsg(){
        String msg = "tst";
        try{
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("localQ",msg);
            return "OK";
        }catch (JmsException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "FAIL";
        }
    }
```

Config Beans:

Connection Factory:

```java
    @Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory(){
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        try{
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setCCSID(1208);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
            mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
    }
```

JMS Template :

```java
  @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws JMSException {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
```

I tried this also for the JMS connection factory:

```java
   @Bean
    public JmsConnectionFactory createConnectionFactory() throws JMSException{
        JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance( JmsConstants.JAKARTA_WMQ_PROVIDER );
        JmsConnectionFactory factory = ff.createConnectionFactory();
        factory.setObjectProperty( WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, Integer.valueOf( WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT ) );
        factory.setStringProperty( WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, host );
        factory.setObjectProperty( WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, port );
        factory.setStringProperty( WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManager );
        factory.setStringProperty( WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channel );
        factory.setStringProperty( WMQConstants.USERID, user );
        factory.setStringProperty( WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password );
        return factory;
    }
```

All of which results in :

```
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '-'
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2842)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2763)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2717)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:4155)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiConnectOptions.nullToSpace(JmqiConnectOptions.java:564)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiConnectOptions.setReceiveExitsUserData(JmqiConnectOptions.java:560)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.getConnectOptions(WMQConnection.java:1528)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:388)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8683)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8023)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:322)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createContext(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:481)
```

Comment: IBM MQ v9.0.4 only supports Java 7 and Java 8.

Comment: @JoshMc  tried IBM MQ version 9.3.2, still the same

Comment: 9.3.2 supports only 8, 11, 17.

Comment: Thank u but the issue was the windows region, while formatting the message in JMS the format is not recognized. @JoshMc

Comment: That is good to know.   But use Java 20 at your own risk,  IBM won't support you if you need to open a ticket.

Comment: You should post a self answer with details of the problem and your solution.